# How to get the standard and custom object API name, field API Name, data type for all field

Tags: custom-object, metadata-api

continue the quetion
  ,length of the numeric field and description of all object and field.

i tried through eclipse but i am not getting it can you please suggest a viable solution for this ?

Comment: Do you want to export this details from your org? - If yes then you can try this app - http://schemalister.herokuapp.com/ . You just need to provide username and all the objects metadata will be retrieved in excel file.

Comment: I tried through the Schemalister but it's giving Application error, seems like i have aroud 250 objects and it has many number of field's could you please suggest the right way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need describe call to fetch all objets information.

```
for ( Schema.SObjectType o : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values() )
{
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objResult = o.getDescribe();
    system.debug( 'Sobject:::' + objResult );
    system.debug( 'Sobject API Name:::' + objResult.getName() );
    system.debug( 'Sobject Label Name:::' + objResult.getLabel() );   
}
```

To retrieve Object and Field Information :

```
// sObject types to describe
String[] types = new String[]{'Account','Student__c'};

// Describe call to retrieve Object information
Schema.DescribeSobjectResult[] results = Schema.describeSObjects(types);

// For each returned result, get some info
for(Schema.DescribeSobjectResult res : results) {
    System.debug('sObject Label: ' + res.fields.getMap());
    System.debug('Fields: ' + res.fields.getMap());
    System.debug('Number of fields: ' + res.fields.getMap().size());
    System.debug(res.isCustom() ? 'This is a custom object.' : 'This is a standard object.');
}
```

See the [Schema Lister](http://schemalister.herokuapp.com/), This tool uses the Salesforce Metadata API to build a list of objects, fields and field attributes from within your Salesforce Org.

Comment: we want the all details for all the objects in one go.

Answer (score 0):

There are AppExchange tools that can do this for Salesforce some of which allow extract to files, [Octopus](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5cEKEAZ) by Astrea is one that I have used that will do this to word or pdf documents but is only free for the first 5 uses, after that you have to pay for it. This does not pick up the description information but does display help text for custom fields.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question doesn't ask for a specific way to get it, I suggest the [Salesforce Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-inspector/aodjmnfhjibkcdimpodiifdjnnncaafh) for Chrome/Chromium. The same thing also exists for Firefox.